# centos vim: how to make it better?

Tags: vim, centos

Hey I have a centos installation, but I found the vim within it is quite worse than the one in ubuntu. I don't know why. I have copied the configurations from ubuntu but the behavior is still not the same, the difference:

1. I can't use arrow keys in insert mode, when I press "UP", the 'A' will be inserted into the content, and vice versa for all the other arrow keys, what should I set to make arrow keys working right in insert mode? (In view mode it's ok).
2. I can't copy a line using 'yy' and then close it and then open another file and then 'p' paste to the opened file. Looks like no clipboard suppored across multiple files.
3. I can't use history feature(I can't go the the line number that I visited last time, the cursor will always go into the first line when I open the last opened file)

I appreciate the helps!

Comment: Can you compare the outputs of the `:version` command?

Comment: ubuntu: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Apr 16 2010 12:36:35) centos: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Sep 19 2009 17:23:40)

Comment: #1 at least sounds like an issue with your terminal settings rather than with `vim`.

Comment: hi I am using putty to access. the settings is the same, can you suggest what I should change?>

Comment: @Bin Try playing with the settings in `Terminal > Keyboard`, specifically the "The function keys and keypad".

Comment: Oh, I found 'set nocompatible' can resolve this problem!!!

Comment: @Bin Chen: Try `vim -N` (not Vi compatible) and see if that improves the behavior.  If so, you can look for a `.vimrc` file that sets up non-compatible mode plus other features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
in the ubuntu machine, open a file with vim
and do

```
:mksession ubuntu.vim
```

put the file ubuntu.vim in the second machine, where you would type the following:

```
vim -S ubuntu.vim
```

if you now have the same behavior you just need to check what you need to add in
your .vimrc from the file ubuntu.vim.
If you don't have the same behavior maybe you will have some errors while loading the file...

Comment: in case it does work a good way of checking the differences between the two systems would be to create a second file using the same procedure (open vim and type :mksession centos.vim) and then check the differences in the two files ubuntu.vim and centos.vim